# How to use functions for making decisions

Tags: bash

I am porting a 'Choose Your Own Adventure' game to Linux. The game took user input and used it to determine a "path".

How I'd do it on windows:

```
echo Do you turn left or right?
set /p a=
if %a%==left goto left
if %a%==right goto right
:left
echo You go left.
echo Now, do you continue down the cave or...

:right
echo You go right.
echo Now, do you... ect.
```

How do I do this in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an almost 1:1 translation of your code to bash can be written with functions like this

```
#!/bin/bash

left() {
  echo You go left.
  echo Now, do you continue down the cave or...
}

right() {
  echo You go right.
  echo Now, do you... ect.
}


echo -n "Do you turn left or right? "
read a
[ $a = "left" ]  && left
[ $a = "right" ] && right
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no `goto` in bash. You can use `case` for your game instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

pos=start

while [[ $pos != quit ]] ; do
    case $pos in
        (start) echo You are in a room. You can go left or right.
            until [[ $pos == @(left|right) ]] ; do
                read pos
            done
            ;;

        (left) echo You go left.
            # ...
            ;;

        (right) echo You go right.
            pos=quit
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: This also echoes "You go right" for an infinite amount of times.

Comment: @JaredKauffman: You have to add code to the `left` and `right` parts, similar to the `start` one.